# Fetch Array data from Javascript Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have such kind of array in javasript:

```
{id: 'ZM', name: "Zambia"},
{id: 'MZ', name: "Mozambique"},
{id: 'BW', name: "Botswana"},
{id: 'NA', name: "Namibia"},
{id: 'MW', name: "Malawi"},
{id: 'ZW', name: "Zimbabwe"},
```

How can i fetch perticuler array record by id('BW',MW)?
Eg. After Fetch I want to array record like below:

```
{id: 'BW', name: "Botswana"},
{id: 'MW', name: "Malawi"}
```

Comment: Look into `Array.prototype.filter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
function fetch(array, ids) {
    return array.filter(function (el) {return ids.indexOf(el.id) !== -1;});
}
```

It returns a filter version of the array containing only those IDs in the ids array. YOu can use it like so:

```
var arr = [ {id: 'ZM', name: "Zambia"},
{id: 'MZ', name: "Mozambique"},
{id: 'BW', name: "Botswana"},
{id: 'NA', name: "Namibia"},
{id: 'MW', name: "Malawi"},
{id: 'ZW', name: "Zimbabwe"}];

function fetch(array, ids) {
    return array.filter(function (el) {return ids.indexOf(el.id) !== -1;});
}

fetch(arr, ["BW","MW"]);//Outputs [{id: 'BW', name: "Botswana"},{id: 'MW', name: "Malawi"}]
```

Comment: No problem :) if you think this is the correct answer can you please accept it(Click the checkmark under this post, on the left.)